# Open specific panel in jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using a jQuery accordion on a wordpress blog. It adds panels whenever the author uploads new articles (new article = new panel). How can I make it, that when loading the page, the first panel is open? I've read several tutorials, but it all seems, these rely on a collapsible accordion that is not altered via php? I figure, that I need some kind of function that determines how many panels there are before it can trigger the first panel to be open?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}

(function($) {
// What does the accordion plugin do?
$.fn.accordion = function(options) {

  if (!this.length) { return this; }

  var opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.accordion.defaults, options);

  this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this).find('dl');

    var $all_panels = $this.find("dd");

    if(Modernizr.cssanimations)
    {
      $this.find("dt:first .arrow").addClass();
    }
    else
    {
      $this.find("dt:first .arrow").addClass();
    }

    $this.find("dt > a").on('click', function(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
      {

       $all_panels.slideUp();
       var $active = $('dl .active').removeClass('active');

       $(this).parent().next().slideDown().addClass('active');
       $(this).parent().addClass('active');

       if(Modernizr.cssanimations)
       {
         $active.filter('dt').find('.arrow').removeClass('down-anim');
         $(this).parent().find('.arrow').addClass('down-anim');
       }
       else
       {
         $active.filter('dt').find('.arrow').removeClass('down');
         $(this).parent().find('.arrow').addClass('down');
       }
      }

    });

  });

  return this;
};

// default options
$.fn.accordion.defaults = {};
})(jQuery);



// call plugin
$(".accordion").accordion()

});
```

in my PHP-Code, I call `<dl>` & `<dt>` once and send it through the loop, so it multiplies according to how many articles there are.

So here is the html it gives me:

```
<div class="accordion">
 <dl>
  <dt>
   <a href="#"><span class="arrow"></span><div class="accordion-user"></div></a>
  </dt>
  <dd>
   <img class="author_image" src=".../my_directory/150x190.png">
   <div class="author_wrapper">
   </div>
  </dd>
 </dl>
 <dl>
  ...
 </dl>
 <dl>
  ...
 </dl>
</div>
```

…and so on…

Thanks so much :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm also using modernizr.

Comment: It would be useful if you show a bit of your HTML (the PHP is irrelevant, but the resulting HTML would be useful). Where in your HTML is the javascript referenced? If you reference it in `<head>`, you need to wait for the document to be ready, see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Hey Niels, yes – the javascript is referenced in my `<head>`

Comment: does anyone have a solution?